# Missing a text-domain esc_attr_e

Tags: php, functions

I have a warning via the [Theme Check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/):

> Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function `esc_attr_e`, with the arguments 'no-image-selected'

Code:

```
data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( $l10n['no-image-selected'] ); ?>
```

I tried:

```
data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( $l10n['no-image-selected'], 'mytextdomain' ); ?>
```

But I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about the error but the strings that are being translated need to be constant strings, not dynamic values.

if `$l10n['no-image-selected']` is already translated then use `esc_attr` and not `esc_attr_e`